How to thank letter writers
I am nearing the end of my PhD and am now applying to postdoc positions. I have had to have my three reference writers submit their letters to a multitude of different application portals, and I feel bad every time I ask for a new submission. How does one thank the letter-writers after everything is done? I plan to send a thank-you card soon after the applications are all in, and then send an update after I accept an offer, but I feel like I should do something more. Are gift cards or other actual gifts acceptable?

This question is similar to: How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AzorAhai-him- I feel that my question is significantly different. It's not about asking for the letter (or asking for anything else); it's about how to express gratitude. If this is unclear, feel free to offer an edit.

Did you read the accepted answer?

@AzorAhai-him-, I don't see an accepted answer.

Oops sorry, clicking around too fast. The top answer.

Gifts of small monetary value are acceptable, especially if there is no possibility of a hint of bribery for actions not yet taken. That is a possible but unusual situation, of course.
But gifts of sentimental value, assuming modest cost, can be meaningful and valued. Over the years, I've been given small presents by foreign students that represent something meaningful to their own home culture. They are "treasures" of the mind and soul, but not expensive for the student.
Yes, thank-you cards and such are fine. Hundred dollar bills within them are not fine. I assume there are some places with rules about such things and you need to be aware. In particular, passing gifts "upward" in some hierarchies is forbidden. But a card is still fine.
Probably the best time to thank your letter writers and other supporters is when you have finalized the position you were seeking. You can bring them up to date on the situation as well as thank them.
It is also a good idea to keep contact with such folks for at least several years after they have helped you. It opens many possibilities both personal and professional.

Thank you. I will refrain from giving gift cards. A related question is that I am not sure what to give my advisor after I graduate, but I figure that will be similar?

Yes, similar, I think.

I like to give people hand made thank you cards in this kind of situation. I gave my previous supervisor a hand made thank you card when he left for a new job at a different institution, and wrote a short note inside expressing my appreciation for specific things he'd done as my supervisor. I like this option because it feels more meaningful than a store bought card when someone has put in a lot of effort on my behalf, but it doesn't have any monetary value so couldn't be perceived as a bribe.
Academics are generally overworked and underappreciated, so writing a bit more inside a card making it clear how much you appreciate the effort they have put in for you is likely to be much more meaningful than a gift! I know my supervisor has held onto cards given to him by previous students for quite a long time.

Writing reference letters is part of my job, and as such I'm paid for it through my salary. Nothing particular is needed to thank me for it. Don't feel bad about it. Chances are you pay university fees, and these pay for recommendation letters as well. I'm not going to complain about a thank you card and a situation update, but I don't expect anything, and for sure nothing more is needed (certainly nothing of material value).
